# What is the folder called /storage/emulated/0/.photoShare/thumb/lcd

Tags: file-management, hidden

[image: File Explorer says it is; it says it isn't Hidden but it is inside a Hidden Folder, namely photoShare]

I have a folder named lcd or Icd (can't tell if it's a lowercase L or an uppercase letter i) which is inside the Hidden Folder called photoShare.
It contains over 300Mbs of images, all of which seem to be duplicates of images elsewhere in my Android Phone (Honor 9 lite).
There is a .thumbs folder beside it. It's 30 odd Mbs and is full of images too.
Oddly, despite many Google searches using every combo of words possible, I can find no mention anywhere of a folder called lcd/Icd, not one mention anywhere.
Question being,

Is it safe to delete the images inside /.photoShare/lcd/Icd?

Comment: it is safe to delete complete folder .photoShare. thumbs are smaller version of pictures for preview, they will be recreated anyway

Comment: @alecxs you mean "it's safe to delete the whole folder .photoShare"

Comment: yes, hidden folders with .dots are usually temporary files

Answer (score 2):

> **.photoShare** is a folder used by Huawei devices for it's Cloud service.

If Huawei's Cloud is enabled on your device, your gallery may have been synced to your Huawei's "personal" cloud storage.

You can turn off the cloud backup option for your photos, but maybe you need this service in case of emergency, where you accidentally deleted your pictures, at least you'll be able to restore what was synced before in the cloud service.

It's safe to delete the folder, but doing it from settings will be better to avoid any data loss if you're syncing your folder with the cloud service.